# Using SQL statement in WHERE method (Codeigniter) to prevent SQL injection

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Does this code protects from sql injection?

```
    $where = "(color = '$color' AND flavor = '$flavor') OR (quality = '$quality' AND price = '$price')";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $result = $this->db->get('fruits');
```

Based on Codeigniter Docs as it say.

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it
>   to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names.

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

Changing the previous statement to this is correct?

```
    $where = "(color = '$color' AND flavor = '$flavor') OR (quality = '$quality' AND price = '$price')";
    $this->db->where($where, NULL, TRUE);
    $result = $this->db->get('fruits');
```

I'm kinda lost or should I use this.

```
    $array = array('color' => $color,
                   'flavor' => $flavor,
                   'quality' => $quality,
                   'price' => $price);
    $where = "(color = ? AND flavor = ?) OR (quality = ? AND price = ?)";
    $this->db->where($where, $array, TRUE);
    $result = $this->db->get('fruits');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the last one. It's not possible detect what to "protect" in other queries.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I used this method
**$this->db->query();**
instead because it has a neat/clean statement and easy to read.